# A question regarding maximum matching M and non-M saturated vertices

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

I encountered a problem when studying for my finals.
I would appreciate it if you guys could give me some tips on how to solve this problem.

Let $G$ be a graph of order $n \geq 2$. Assume $G$ has no isolated vertices. Let $M$ be a maximum matching of $G$ and $x$ the number of vertices in $G$ that are not $M$-saturated.

Show that $x \leq |M|(\Delta (G)-1)$.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to assume that the graph $G$ has no isolated vertices.

Comment: Hint: Any vertex of $G$ that is not $M$-saturated is a neighbor of an $M$-saturated vertex.

Comment: Ah yes, i forgot to include $G$ has no isolated vertices

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It really helped in solving this problem!